# Access to GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController TableView

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I am using GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController and placing the searchBar in a NavigationBar's title view. The Nav bar and the title view have extended height to accommodate another search bar above the Google Places search bar. This all works well except that the Google Places AutoComplete table displays partially UNDER the navigation bar.

Is there any way to access the GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController tableview so that I can manipulate where it is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your view controller setup in a storyboard, make sure to uncheck the **Extend edges Under Top Bars** in both the `UIViewController` and its containing `UINavigationController`

**Swift 3**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
self.navigationController?.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
definesPresentationContext = true
```